# Firebase Android Banning Users

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have an android app that people can write something on chatbox.

They login with google account. And i have their user id which is shown below by $uid

But if there will somebody writing stupid things i want to prevent this person's writing ability.

So how can i make this by using this body. Or what is your suggestion?

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

Comment: filter through slang array?

Comment: no. it is only an example.i just want to know how do i prevent user's writing ability by user id. i think it must not so complex but i don't know firebase very well.

Comment: I would create a database entry called "Banned" under which is a list of banned uids. You can check against that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

First, you have to change your banned user JSON model to follow format.

[image: Change to this format]

> **Path pattern**
>
> /banned-users/$userid: true
>
> **From above image**
>
> /banned-users/fasjdkflksdflad: true

now change your rules to the following way

```
{
  "rules": {
    "messages": {
      "$messageId": {
        ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": "auth.uid != null && !root.child('/banned-users/'+auth.uid).exists()"
      }
    },
  }
}
```

Say you are adding messages to the /messages path with each messages id as $messagesId then your /messages path looks like below

```
{
  "messages": {
    "-KTKvywjwDv4RpYjQglu":{
       "text": "Hey Guys..."
    },
    "-KTKvywjwDv4RpYjQglu":{
       "text": "How you doing ..."
    }
  }
}
```

**Explanation**

According to the rules, any logged in user can read the /messages `".read": "auth.uid != null",` defines that.

To write to message to /messages path, then firebase check for if the (**user is logged in *AND*  /banned-users/user-id path exists**) in firebase. As `auth.uid` is internal firebase variable used when rule validation. `".write": "auth.uid != null && !root.child('/banned-users/'+auth.uid).exists()"` defines that.

you can ignore `.validate` you can achieve this by just using `.write`.

**old answer**

You cannot do it with just security rules.

First, you have to use [Firebase cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events).

Create database trigger on the `/chats` database path. When the new message contains stupid things then you can delete it right away and you can get the user ID and save it to some other path say `/banned-users/<userid>`

Now you can write the .validate rule to check current messaging userid is not on the banned list. Using

`".validate": "!root.child('/banned-users/'+$uid).exists()"`

If you have to completely disable user account then you have to use Firebase Admin API.

Comment: i will add the user ids manually. https://i.hizliresim.com/EylDmB.png   i create this and now when i write this validation to the rules section nobody cant read or write anything. https://i.hizliresim.com/lbYZNB.png    can you please explain step by step? i am so beginner to firebase

Comment: check my updated answer, need more info then let's discuss in chat.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i cant find where is chat section.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do this in rules. You can just disable that person's userID in the "Authentication" section of the [FirebaseConsole](https://console.firebase.google.com)

Screenshot attached below as sample

[image]

This would be much easier compared to adding into the rules where you have to enter the userID manually anyway.